# Comparar datos de dos base de datos SQL Server con VS2013

Tags: c#, sql-server, base-de-datos, visual-studio-2013, comparaciones

Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 te da la posibilidad de comparar datos de Sql Server entre dos base de datos para luego sincronizarlas, yo necesito hacer esa comparacion y sincronizacion de forma automatica y si es en un Wimdows Services mejor, se puede hacer eso? es posible llamar a la herramienta mediante codigo?

Answer (score 0):

Podrias evaluar usar el commando `Data.NewDataComparison`

[Automation Command Reference for Database Features of Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470565(v=vs.100).aspx#CompareData)

en la documentacion veras los parametros que puedes proporcionar para comparar dos schemas

Tambien podrias evaluar

[Compare Schemas by using VSDBCMD.EXE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833435(v=vs.100).aspx#Compare%20Schemas%20by%20using%20VSDBCMD.EXE)

con estas lineas de comando creo que podrias conseguir lo que planteas